# Converting 8 bits in binary to 1 byte

Tags: c++, testing, byte, bit-shift

I have a string of 8 bits and I want to convert it into 1 byte. I am not sure why my function is not working properly. I have 8 bits stored into an array of 8 unsigned chars. This is my method so far:

```
unsigned int bitsToBytes(unsigned char *bits)
{
  unsigned int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 8; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    sum += bits[i];
    sum<<=1;
  }
  return sum;

}

int main()
{
  unsigned char bits[8]='01010111';
  unsigned int byt;
  byt = bitsToBytes(bits);
  cout << byt; //doesn't give me the right result
}
```

Could anyone help to get correct result? Thanks alot!

Comment: With your terminology being completely off, it's hard to know what it is you really want done. What's the "right result" that you didn't get?

Comment: `'0' != 0` and `'1' != 1`.

Comment: `'01010111'` is not what you think it is.

Comment: `unsigned char bits[8]='01010111';` doesn't compile.

Comment: bits[i] is a char not int.

Comment: Among all the other errors you have an out of bounds array access at the start of your loop. `8` is not a valid index for an array of size 8. Array indexes start at zero. Try `for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @LiamLony: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems:

- the loop in your code iterates 9 times, from 8 to 0 inclusive,
- you read `bits[8]` which is an invalid access.
- you add `bits[i]` which is a character with value `'0'` or `'1'`, not a bit value.
- the bits are probably shifted in the wrong order.
- in `main()`, the initializer for the array is incorrect: `unsigned char bits[8] = '01010111';` should be `unsigned char bits[8] = "01010111";`

Here is a modified version:

```c
unsigned int bitsToBytes(unsigned char *bits) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sum = (sum << 1) + (bits[i] - '0');
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char bits[8] = "01010111";
    unsigned int byt;
    byt = bitsToBytes(bits);
    cout << byt;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

1. bits is to short to accommodate 8 chars + null char
2. shuft of the sum has to be done before adding the value
3. Strings are enclosed in `"` not `'`

```
unsigned int bitsToBytes(unsigned char *bits)
{
  unsigned int sum = 0;
  while(*bits)
  {
    sum<<=1;
    sum += *bits++ - '0';
  }
  return sum;

}


int main()
{
  unsigned char bits[]="0101011101100101010101";
  unsigned int byt;
  byt = bitsToBytes(bits);
  std::cout << (unsigned)byt; //doesn't give me the right result
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PjjbGK

https://godbolt.org/z/njaKPn

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218248/discussion-on-answer-by-p-j-converting-8-bits-in-binary-to-1-byte).